# How to do Passing Scroll Keys from MobileSite to MobileNavbar for Section Navigation

Tags: flutter

I have already declared global keys and function to scroll to a specific section with help of other helpful questions asked here. Now the problem is:, how to pass these keys to my `navbar class` so that user onPressed can be taken to that particular section. Also I dont have any scaffold in these classes below as for responsive layout purpose, Its in `HomePage` where according to screen width `MobileSite()` class will be returned.

**Main Code:**

```
// ignore_for_file: prefer_const_constructors, prefer_const_literals_to_create_immutables

import 'package:autoclub/components/navbar/tablet_navbar.dart';
import 'package:autoclub/screens/Desktop/portfolio/PortfolioContainer.dart';
import 'package:autoclub/screens/Mobile/About%20Us/about.dart';
import 'package:autoclub/screens/Mobile/Contact%20Us/mobile_contact_us.dart';
import 'package:autoclub/screens/Mobile/Footer/mobile_footer.dart';
import 'package:autoclub/screens/Mobile/Home/mobile_home.dart';
import 'package:autoclub/screens/Mobile/Portfolio/mobile_portfolio.dart';
import 'package:autoclub/screens/Mobile/Reviews/mobile_reviews.dart';
import 'package:autoclub/screens/Mobile/Services/mobile_services_container.dart';
import 'package:autoclub/screens/Mobile/Why%20Us/mobile_strengths_container.dart';
import 'package:autoclub/screens/Mobile/mobile_stats_bar.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'mobile_navbar.dart';

class MobileSite extends StatefulWidget {
  static const id = 'mobile_site.dart';
  const MobileSite({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MobileSite> createState() => _MobileSiteState();
}

class _MobileSiteState extends State<MobileSite> {
  final ScrollController _controller = ScrollController();

  final GlobalKey section1Key = GlobalKey();
  final GlobalKey section2Key = GlobalKey();
  final GlobalKey section3Key = GlobalKey();
  final GlobalKey section4Key = GlobalKey();
  final GlobalKey section5Key = GlobalKey();
  final GlobalKey section6Key = GlobalKey();
  final GlobalKey section7Key = GlobalKey();

  // Function to scroll to a specific section based on its key
  void _scrollToSection(GlobalKey key) {
    final RenderBox renderBox = key.currentContext!.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
    final offset = renderBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero).dy;
_controller.animateTo(
  offset,
  duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
  curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
);


 }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

final double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
final double screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

return Container(
  width: screenWidth,
  child: SingleChildScrollView(
    controller: _controller,
    child: Column(
      children: [
        //home
        MobileHome(
          key: section1Key,
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 10,),
        Divider(),
        SizedBox(height: 10,),

        //about
        MobileAboutUs(
          key: section2Key,
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 10,),
        Divider(),
        SizedBox(height: 10,),

        //services
        MobileServicesContainer(
          key: section3Key,
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 10,),
        Divider(),
        SizedBox(height: 10,),

        //stats bar
        MobileStatsBar(
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 10,),
        Divider(),
        SizedBox(height: 10,),

        //why us
        MobileWhyUs(
          key: section4Key,
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 10,),

        //portfolio
        MobilePortfolio(
          key: section5Key,
        ),
        Divider(),

        //TODO: add carosuel in between somewhere + add reviews to navbar

        //reviews
        MobileReviews(
          key: section6Key,
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 20,),
        Divider(),
        SizedBox(height: 20,),

        //contact us
        MobileContactUs(
          key: section7Key,
        ),

        //footer
        MobileFooter(),

      ],
    ),
  ),
);


 }
}
```

**Navbar Class' code:**

```
    // ignore_for_file: prefer_const_constructors, prefer_const_literals_to_create_immutables

import 'package:autoclub/screens/Mobile/Home/mobile_home.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../../components/constants.dart';


class MobileNavbar extends StatefulWidget {
  const MobileNavbar({super.key});

  @override
  State<MobileNavbar> createState() => _MobileNavbarState();
}

class _MobileNavbarState extends State<MobileNavbar> {


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    final double screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return Drawer(
      child: ListView(
        children: [
          Container(
            width: 100,
            height: 150,
            color: kGreyColor,
            child: Image.asset('assets/images/logo.png'),
          ),
          BuildNavlinkTile(
            icon: Icons.home,
            title: 'Home',
            onTap: () { Navigator.pushNamed(context, MobileHome.id); },
          ),
          BuildNavlinkTile(
            icon: Icons.info,
            title: 'About Us',
            onTap: () { },
          ),
          BuildNavlinkTile(
            icon: Icons.miscellaneous_services,
            title: 'Services',
            onTap: () { },
          ),
          BuildNavlinkTile(
            icon: Icons.quiz,
            title: 'Why Us',
            onTap: () { },
          ),
          BuildNavlinkTile(
            icon: Icons.image,
            title: 'Portfolio',
            onTap: () { },
          ),
          BuildNavlinkTile(
            icon: Icons.reviews,
            title: 'Reviews',
            onTap: () { },
          ),
          BuildNavlinkTile(
            icon: Icons.call,
            title: 'Contact Us',
            onTap: () { },
          ),
          Divider(),
          BuildNavlinkTile(
            icon: Icons.exit_to_app,
            title: 'Exit',
            onTap: () { Navigator.pop(context);},
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );

  }
}

class BuildNavlinkTile extends StatelessWidget {
  const BuildNavlinkTile({
    super.key,
    required this.title,
    required this.onTap,
    required this.icon,
  });

  final String title;
  final VoidCallback onTap;
  final IconData icon;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      leading: Icon(icon),
      title: Text(title),
      onTap: (){ },
    );
  }
}
```